# Saving RichText Box's Text as Text File

Tags: c#, richtextbox, savefiledialog

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save_file = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (save_file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK&&save_file.FileName.Length>0)
        {

            save_file.DefaultExt = "txt";
            WriteBox.SaveFile(save_file.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
    }
```

This isn't working, Every time file is opened computer asks for a program to choose neither it allows to set a default program. What's Missing there, anyone help :)

Comment: Its RichTextBox's Name

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save_file = new SaveFileDialog();
    save_file.DefaultExt = "txt";
    save_file.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (save_file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK&&save_file.FileName.Length>0)
    {
        WriteBox.SaveFile(save_file.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Copied the exact code, no help ..! problem persists

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? Did you tried clean build your solution?